# Localhost very slow on Windows 7 (tried other suggestions..nothing worked)

Tags: apache2, localhost

I know this has been asked before but I have tried every suggestion i've found but nothing seems to work

My localhost seems to take forever to load pages (up to 30 secs).  Ihave the follwoing installed on Windows 7

I am running:

- Apache 2.4
- PHP 5.4.9
- MySQL 5.5.25

Things I have tried:

1. Edited the hosts file in *Windows\System32\drivers\etc*

   # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.

   ```
          127.0.0.1       localhost
   ```
2. Edit the http.conf file to give a ServerName

   # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.

   #
   ServerName 127.0.0.1:80

Has anyone got any other suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)